# How do you pass in default values to a subprocess program that asks for command-line arguments?

Tags: python, vue.js, command-line, subprocess, vue-cli

I know it is quite possible to run programs from within a python script using the `subprocess` module, but what I can't seem to figure out is if it's possible to go a bit deeper and pass in default arguments to a subprocess that requires command-line inputs. Please see a specific example below:

I want to create a new vue project using the vue-cli from a python script because aside from initializing the project I want to automatically copy/move files around within the new project directory space. So after doing some setup I want to have subprocess run the following code: `subprocess.run(['vue', 'init', 'web pack-simple', '<project-name>']` which is the equivalent of running `$ vue init web pack-simple <project-name>` directly in the command line.

Here is where I would please like some advice. When directly running `$ vue init web pack-simple <project-name>` in the command-line I then go through a CLI where it asks me the **project-name**, and then you hit *'Enter'* and then it asks you for a **project description**, and then you hit *'Enter'* and then it asks if you're **using sass**, etc.

Is there some way through the `subprocess` module that I can pass in and enter default/specified values automatically into this vue-cli such that whenever the vue-cli asks for **project-name** and **project-description**, **etc.** those are automatically filled out?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: The *program* you are trying to run queries the *user* for information and waits for a response? Or are you just trying to submit command line arguments to the *program*?

Comment: @wwii The first one, so specifically the program I am trying to run queries the user for information and waits for a response

Comment: It sounds like you need your program to launch a 2nd program which will ask your program (thinking its a person) for input.  And you need your code to fill out that needed input automatically.  Is that correct?  And does this have to be done through subprocess?  Or are you open to alternate libraries for that part of the job?

Comment: Yes, you can send data over a pipe to your subprocess. If you can do it all in one go, it can be done by a call to `.communicate()` that both takes input on `stdin` and gives output to `stdout` and `stderr`. However, it is likely simpler to use `pexpect` rather than rolling your own solution with `subprocess`.

Comment: @RockAndRoleCoder Yes that is exactly correct. No it does not have to be done through `subprocess`, I am happy to use any method/library that would work. My only constraint is I would prefer to be able to do it within a Python script.

Comment: @JohanL Okay, I will check out the `pexpect` library, thanks